# Path in binary tree

Tags: list, scheme, b-tree

I'm preparing for my exams and I did almost everything, but this exercise I don't understand. How to make a function that will search for a path in a binary tree from a specific value.

Here is an example:

```
(define tree '(1 (2 (3) (4)) (5 (6 (7) (8)) (9))))
(find-path tree 4)
(1 2 4)
```

Comment: Have you not looked at the various tree traversal algorithms (depth first, breadth first etc) ?

Answer (score 1):

I start sketching out some code -

```
(define (find t q) ;; find q in t

(path empty) ;; the return path will be a list, we'll start it off as an empty list

(if (empty? t) ;; fundamental laws: always check for empty list first
    #f         ;; if the tree is empty, there is nothing to find, we use #f to signal this
    (if (eq? q (car t)) ;; otherwise we can check if the node matches q ...
        ;; wups we can't do eq? test yet, it's possible `(car t)` is a list of nodes
        ))
```

How do I see this? I look at our input list -

```
(define tree '(1 (2 (3) (4)) (5 (6 (7) (8)) (9))))
```

1. We *always* check for `empty?` first
2. If the list is not empty, we know we have:

   - at least one element, `(car tree)`
   - the rest of the elements, `(cdr tree)`
3. I visualize the elements of the outermost list; there are only three:

   - `1`
   - `(2 (3) (4))`
   - `(5 (6 (7) (8)) (9))`
4. The first element was `1` so I thought I could reach for `eq?` and check if it matched `q` right away
5. I noticed the second element was a different *type*. Intuitively we cannot match a single element against a list of elements, so we must handle the `list?` case *before* we attempt `eq?`

Fix my boo boo -

```
(define (find t q)

(path empty)

(if (empty? t)
    #f
    (if (list? (car t))
        ;; when the node is a list of nodes
        (if (eq? q (car t))
            ;; when the node matches q
            ;; when the node does not match q
            )))
```

Collapse chained `if` to `cond` for better readability -

```
(define (find t q)

(path empty)

(cond ((empty? t)
        #f)
      ((list? (car t))
       ;; when the node is a list of nodes
       )
      ((eq? q (car t))
       ;; when the node matches q
       )
      (else
       ;; when the node does not match q
       ))
```

The code is flatter and nicer to read now. Some of those blanks are tricky to fill in, but I am drawn to the second blank; when `q` equals`(car t)` that means we found a match and it's time to return the `path` -

```
(define (find t q)

(path empty)

(cond ((empty? t)
        #f)
      ((list? (car t))
       ;; when the node is a list of nodes
       ;; we'll come back to this ...
       )
      ((eq? q (car t))
       (cons q path)) ;; return the path with the final node
      (else
       ;; when the nodes does not match q
       ;; and save this for later too ...
       ))
```

Ok, that wasn't so bad. So I checked when `(car t)` matches `q`, now I have to say what happens when it doesn't match. When `(car t)` doesn't match, I'll add it to the `path` and somehow check to see if `q` matches any of the node's children, `(cdr t)` -

```
(define (find t q)

(path empty)

(cond ((empty? t)
        #f)
      ((list? (car t))
       ;; when node is a list of nodes
       ;; we'll come back to this ...
       )
      ((eq? q (car t))
       (cons q path))
      (else

       ;; add the node to the path ...
       (cons (car t) path)

       ;; check the node's children for a match
       (find (cdr t) q)

       ;; this doesn't quite work ...
       ))
```

I run into a situation where we need to update `path` with the new node and I need to call `find` which does not have `path` parameter. To remedy this, I introduce a loop which allows us to repeatedly evaluate an expression with any arguments we specify -

```
(define (find t q)

(let loop ;; lazily and sloppily insert a named loop

((path empty) ;; initialize the parameters that will change
 (t t))

(cond ((empty? t) ;; the expression to repeat, (cond ...)
        #f)
      ((list? (car t))
       ;; when the node is a list of nodes
       )
      ((eq? q (car t))
       (cons q path))
      (else
       (loop (cons (car t) path) ;; updated path
             (cdr t))))          ;; updated tree
```

The `else` clause taught me how to match against a node's children, which is a list of nodes. That will certainly make it easier to deal with that last blank in the code, which is what to do when the node is a list of nodes! -

```
(define (find t q)

(let loop

((path empty)
 (t t))

(cond ((empty? t)
        #f)
      ((list? (car t))

       ;; we could just recur the loop with 
       (loop path
             (car t))

       ;; but what about (cdr t) in this case?
       (loop path
             (cdr t))

      ((eq? q (car t))
       (cons q path))
      (else
       (loop (cons (car t) path)
             (cdr t))))
```

The final problem here is I have two (2) lists to check; `(car t)` is determined to be a list, and `(cdr t)` is a list. I must check both of them. The simple solution is to combine the two `loop` calls with `or`. If one `loop` returns `#f`, the other will be checked -

```
(define (find t q)

(let loop

((path empty)
 (t t))

(cond ((empty? t)
        #f)
      ((list? (car t))
       (or (loop path   ;; or represents dysjunction!
             (car t))
           (loop path
             (cdr t))))
      ((eq? q (car t))
       (cons q path))
      (else
       (loop (cons (car t) path)
             (cdr t))))
```

Fix up the parentheses, run the automatic indenter -

```
(define (find t q)
  (let loop
    ((path empty)
     (t t))
    (cond ((empty? t)
           #f)
          ((list? (car t))
           (or (loop path
                     (car t))
               (loop path
                     (cdr t))))
          ((eq? q (car t))
           (cons q path))
          (else
           (loop (cons (car t) path)
                 (cdr t))))))

(define tree '(1 (2 (3) (4)) (5 (6 (7) (8)) (9))))

(find tree 4)
;; '(4 2 1)

(find tree 8)
;; (8 6 5 1)

(find tree 9)
;; (9 5 1)
```

Observe that the result is reversed because indeed the `path` is constructed in reverse order. The exit condition that returns the path simply needs call `reverse` before returning -

```
(define (find t q)
  (let loop
    ((path empty)
     (t t))
    (cond ((empty? t)
           #f)
          ((list? (car t))
           (or (loop path
                     (car t))
               (loop path
                     (cdr t))))
          ((eq? q (car t))
           (reverse (cons q path))) ;; don't forget to reverse!
          (else
           (loop (cons (car t) path)
                 (cdr t))))))

(define tree '(1 (2 (3) (4)) (5 (6 (7) (8)) (9))))

(find tree 4)
;; '(1 2 4)

(find tree 8)
;; (1 5 6 8)

(find tree 9)
;; (1 5 9)
```

Comment: disclaimer: I generally don't offer help on questions that show no attempt to solve the problem, especially homework questions. However I know how frustrating it can be to feel stuck. In the end, my goal is to teach you how to think about the problem rather than simply give you the answer. I hope this approach offers some guidance and please let me know if I can explain anything I didn't cover.